# C# Line in AndroidManifest.xml reapears after deleteing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-manifest

i got this error in my androidmanifest:
[image: error]
so i deleted this line:
[image: deletedline]
but when i build the aplication and click the error again, it shows me that line again, and it's there, even tho i deleted it earlier.
So my question is how can i fix the error and why is the line still there after i deleted it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you editing the *generated manifest file in debug time*.

1 - Please, try to open you manifest file under `Properties` folder. Then delete the line.

2 - Clean the project.

3 - Build again.